# Passing two columns to a udf in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe containing two columns,one is data and the other column is 
 character count in that data field.

```
Data    Count
Hello   5
How     3
World   5
```

I want to change value of column data based on the value in count column. How can this be achieved? I tried this using an udf :

```
invalidrecords.withColumn("value",appendDelimiterError(invalidrecords("value"),invalidrecords("a_cnt")))
```

This seems to fail, is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: yes it seems to be correct way

Comment: You need to make sure your udf is a function of type `(String, Int) => String`, for example.

Comment: only that your column names are different

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's an easy way of doing it

first you create a `dataframe`

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val invalidrecords = Seq(
  ("Hello", 5),
  ("How", 3),
  ("World", 5)
).toDF("Data", "Count")
```

you should have

```
+-----+-----+
|Data |Count|
+-----+-----+
|Hello|5    |
|How  |3    |
|World|5    |
+-----+-----+
```

Then you define udf function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def appendDelimiterError = udf((data: String, count: Int) => "value with error" )
```

And you call using `withColumn` as

```
invalidrecords.withColumn("value",appendDelimiterError(invalidrecords("Data"),invalidrecords("Count"))).show(false)
```

You should have output as

```
+-----+-----+----------------+
|Data |Count|value           |
+-----+-----+----------------+
|Hello|5    |value with error|
|How  |3    |value with error|
|World|5    |value with error|
+-----+-----+----------------+
```

You can write your logic instead of returning a string from `udf` function

**Edited**

Answering your requirements in the comment below would require you to change the udf function and withColumn as below

```
def appendDelimiterError = udf((data: String, count: Int) => {
  if(count < 5) s"convert value to ${data} - error"
  else data
} )

invalidrecords.withColumn("Data",appendDelimiterError(invalidrecords("Data"),invalidrecords("Count"))).show(false)
```

you should have output as

```
+----------------------------+-----+
|Data                        |Count|
+----------------------------+-----+
|Hello                       |5    |
|convert value to How - error|3    |
|World                       |5    |
+----------------------------+-----+
```

Comment: I would like to change the value of Data column itself like if count is less than expected append error to value in column data. For eg. convert value in row 2 to How - error

Comment: please check my updated answer :) I am using 5 as expected count

Comment: Still gives me an error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: DelimitedFileProcessTesting$$anonfun$appendDelimiterError$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function1
`

Comment: what is your schema of the dataframe? I guess your count column is other datatype than int.

Comment: No I even tried printing the DF schema it gives count column as IntegerType

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148884/discussion-between-rohan-oswal-and-ramesh-maharjan).

Comment: Good stuff, sir.