# Create 128 bit hash of Spark row, store as new column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hash

I need to add a column to a dataFrame that is a hash of each row. The goal is to use this hash to uniquely identify this row. I will have upwards of 100,000,000 rows, so that is why the hash needs to be so large. I am aware of the built-in spark hash, but unfortunately it is only 32 bits, and would result in a very large number of hash collisions. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Create a UDF function that accepts multiple arguments (one for each column), calculates the 128-bit hash and returns it.  Call that function with `withColumn()`.  UDF example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44971087/215945

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in `md5` function since it is 128 bits. But it doesn't accept multiple arguments so have to `concat` the values together. Also need to handle different datatypes and null values.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, md5, concat, cast, lit}

val tab_w_hash = tab.withColumn("hash128", md5(concat(tab.columns.map(x => coalesce(col(x).cast("string"),lit(""))) : _*)))
```